# Summon Aux for higher-kinded type without reference to the original

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, type-level-computation

I am trying to use the Aux pattern with a higher kinded type and not have to specify the parameter of the higher-kinded type until afterward. This is similar to the SO question described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581986/aux-pattern-for-higher-kinded-types) but with one significant difference, I'm going the other way around, i.e. from an implicit def back to an aux.

```
// The are types that I want to convert to various things
sealed trait ConversionType
trait CaseA extends ConversionType
object CaseA extends CaseA // In this case, convert to an optional
trait CaseB extends ConversionType
object CaseB extends CaseB // In this case, convert to a future etc...

trait Converter[Prefix] {
  type Paramd[_]
  def create[N](n:N): Paramd[N]
}

// Create the mechanism to convert from the cases, only doing case A for now...
object Converter {
  type Aux[Prefix, Ret[_]] = Converter[Prefix] { type Paramd[_] = Ret[_] }

  // *** Error happens here! ***
  def apply[Prefix](implicit p:Converter[Prefix]): Aux[Prefix, p.Paramd] = p

  implicit def makeOptionParamd: Aux[CaseA, Option] =
    new Converter[CaseA] {
      type Paramd[_] = Option[_]
      override def create[N](n:N): Paramd[N] = Option[N](n)
    }
}

// This seems to be fine...
val v = Converter.apply[CaseA].create("test")
```

I get the following compile error on the above noted line:

```
Error:(97, 78) type mismatch;
 found   : p.type (with underlying type Test.this.Converter[Prefix])
 required: Test.Converter.Aux[Prefix,p.Paramd]
    (which expands to)  Test.this.Converter[Prefix]{type Paramd[_] = p.Paramd[_]}
    def apply[Prefix](implicit p:Converter[Prefix]): Aux[Prefix, p.Paramd] = p
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want is

```
object Converter {
  type Aux[Prefix, Ret[_]] = Converter[Prefix] { type Paramd[A] = Ret[A] }

  // compiles
  def apply[Prefix](implicit p:Converter[Prefix]): Aux[Prefix, p.Paramd] = p

  implicit def makeOptionParamd: Aux[CaseA, Option] =
    new Converter[CaseA] {
      type Paramd[A] = Option[A]
      override def create[N](n:N): Paramd[N] = Option[N](n)
    }
}
```

When you write

```
type Paramd[_] = Ret[_]
```

the `_` in the left and the right parts are unrelated. It's the same as

```
type Paramd[A] = Ret[_]

type Paramd[A] = Ret[B] forSome { type B }
```

So `Aux[Prefix, p.Paramd]` with your definition is equivalent to `Converter[Prefix] { type Paramd[A] = p.Paramd[_] }`, and `p` doesn't have this type because `p.Paramd[A]` is not `p.Paramd[_]`.