# Auto-Inferring a higher-kinded Aux Parameter from an Argument

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, type-level-computation

On an earlier SO post I asked how to create use the Aux pattern with a higher kinded type ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411471/summon-aux-for-higher-kinded-type-without-reference-to-the-original), that had a great reply!). Now based on the reply, I am trying to take the abstraction a little but further and have the actual generic parameter be inferred from an argument's type. Trouble is, it seems having trouble differentiating `X` from `X.type`. Here's my code:

```
// The are types that I want to convert to various things
sealed trait ConversionType
trait CaseA extends ConversionType
object CaseA extends CaseA // In this case, convert to an optional
trait CaseB extends ConversionType
object CaseB extends CaseB // In this case, convert to a future etc...

trait Converter[Prefix] {
  type Paramd[_]
  def create[N](n:N): Paramd[N]
}

// Create the mechanism to convert from the cases, only doing case A for now...
object Converter {
  type Aux[Prefix, Ret[_]] = Converter[Prefix] { type Paramd[N] = Ret[N] }

  // Shouldn't `Prefix` be automatically inferred?
  def apply[Prefix](prefix:Prefix)(implicit p:Converter[Prefix]): Aux[Prefix, p.Paramd] = p

  implicit def makeOptionParamd: Aux[CaseA, Option] =
    new Converter[CaseA] {
      type Paramd[N] = Option[N]
      override def create[N](n:N): Paramd[N] = Option[N](n)
    }
}

// This works
val v = Converter.apply[CaseA](CaseA).create("test")
// **** This breaks! Why? ****
val vv = Converter.apply(CaseA).create("test")
```

The following errors occour on the broken line above:

```
Error:(135, 29) could not find implicit value for parameter p: Test.this.Converter[Test.this.CaseA.type]
    val vv = Converter.apply(CaseA).create("test")

Error:(135, 29) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit p: Test.this.Converter[SchemaMaker.this.CaseA.type])Test.this.Converter.Aux[SchemaMaker.this.CaseA.type,p.Paramd] in object Converter.
Unspecified value parameter p.
    val vv = Converter.apply(CaseA).create("test")
```

So the compiler doesn't connect the dots between the object `CaseA` and the type `CaseA`? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your object `CaseA` is at the same time

- of type `CaseA.type` (because it's the singleton object)
- of type `CaseA` (because it extends `CaseA`)

When you invoke

```
val vv = Converter.apply(CaseA).create("test")
```

the inferred type `Prefix` is `CaseA.type` (the singleton object type), and no implicit can be found for that type.

Even more explicitly:

```
val works = Converter.apply(CaseA: CaseA).create("test")
val fails = Converter.apply(CaseA: CaseA.type).create("test")
```

The absolutely shortest possible change that would force your code to compile would be to add a single `-` in front of `Prefix` to make `Converter` contravariant:

```
trait Converter[-Prefix] {
  type Paramd[_]
  def create[N](n:N): Paramd[N]
}
```

but I'm not sure whether this is what you want, because I don't know what you are attempting to achieve with the all this fancy machinery.