# How do I execute a list of effects?

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I have a value of this type:

```scala
val effects : List[EitherT[Future, Error, Foo]] = ...
```

How do I run through the list and execute those effects? I did

```scala
effects.traverse
```

But that method is not defined for that type.

Comment: _"execute those effects"_ a future is eager so it is already running, maybe you want to collect the results? What is the type you want at the end? `EitherT[Future, Error, List[Foo]]`? Also, have you already imported `cats.syntax.all._`?

Comment: Futures are already executed at the time it's created.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah I was missing that import. And then I did `effects.sequence` and I get EitherT[Future, Error, List[Foo]]`

Comment: My understanding is that each of those futures in the `effects` list will get exectued when sequence is applied

Comment: @Mojo no they are already being executing; they nay already have finished. `Futures` are **eager** as such they are side-effecting by nature and you can not reason about them as other pure effects. If instead of `Future` you would have an `IO` then yeah, they wouldn't have been executed yet, neither after the `sequence`, only when you tell them to be executed.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez how do I improve the type inference on sequence? I've followed this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/50499152/10290548 to add in that compiler option but still getting a problem. Shall I set up a new question?

Comment: [wartremover:Any] Inferred type containing Any: [B]cats.data.EitherT[Future,Error,B]

Comment: type `B` is List[Foo]

Comment: @Mojo not sure what you are talking about, the best would be to close this question since a missing import can be categorized a simple typo and then open a new one explaining your new problem with a code snippet reproducing the issue and information like your **Scala** version and **cats** version as well as what you tried to fix the problem. Try to be very clear with the problem since I really did not understand what it was from that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it's better to get rid of `Future` when you are declaring some list of effects and want to execute them and gather effects in one list after. It's better to use `IO` or another lazy evaluated effect.

So, if you just need to `traverse` on `Future[List[A]]`:

```scala
import cats.data.EitherT
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.future._

implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

case class Foo()
val effects : List[EitherT[Future, Error, Foo]] = ???
def f(e: EitherT[Future, Error, Foo]): Future[Either[Error, Foo]] = ???
val result: Future[List[Either[Error, Foo]]] = effects.traverse(f)
```

this code compiles and all you need is implement `f`. You need to add `import cats.instances.future._` to have traverse function in `Furure`.

but better way to construct you process on something like `IO`:

```scala
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.effect.IO
val effects : List[EitherT[IO, Error, Foo]] = ???
def f(e: EitherT[IO, Error, Foo]): IO[Either[Error, Foo]] = ???
val result: IO[List[Either[Error, Foo]]] = effects.traverse(f)
```

and call it using `unsafeRunAsync`.